# nothing happens on button click for video if it's playing

Tags: jquery, html, binding, callback, html5-video

How could I make it so that if I have a button separate from the video, and you click it, it polays as normal if the video is not playing, but if it is, then nothing happens with it?

I'm guessing it would be something like

```
$('theButtonToClick').bind('click', function() {
//stuff happens to play it
myVideo.bind("playing", function() {
    $('theButtonToClick').bind('click', return, false);
});
});
```

I actually have the video set to myVideo, so it knoe=ws what you mean when you call it, and the call backs [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#mediaevents) work on `bind` events....

Am I leaving anything out?Edit: oh geez, I forgot, the button is part of a set of buttons in a list...
**EDIT** sorry, i relized this wasn't very clear. I want to disable a button in a list element whilst it's corresponding video is playing...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
play.addEventListener('click',playControl,false);
function playControl() {
  if (video.paused == false) {
    video.pause();
  } else {
    video.play();
  }
}
```